# Using CipherInputStream with Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I am encountering an issue when using CipherInputStream over a network connection. I have read a few questions and articles on this and experimented based on their contents but to no avail. I have created a stripped down example of my issue in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

My example contains two executable classes:

- EchoSocketTest – This is a simple server application that listens on
  a port echos back to the sender whatever it receives
- EchoClientTest – This is a simple client. It preforms 3 tests

Test 1. Creates a connection to the echo server, sends a piece of data and displays what it gets back.

Test 2. Creates a connection to the echo server but uses CipherOutputStream to encrypt the data it 
sends. It sends a piece of data and displays what it gets back.

Test 3. The same as Test 2 however it tries to use CipherInputStream to decrypt the data.

In my example test 1 and test 2 preform perfectly and give the correct output. However test 3 fails and the message "Error nothing read from socket" is displayed.
I have verified that the encrypt and decrypt parts work by creating another test that uses a FileInputStream and that works as expected. I have a feeling the problem is something to do with padding but I have experimented with various options suggested online.

Code and example output follows:

**EchoSocketTest:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class EchoSocketTest {

    public static class Connection extends Thread {
        Socket m_Sock = null;
        PrintWriter m_out = null;
        BufferedReader m_in = null;
        public Connection(Socket p_Sock) throws Exception {
            m_Sock = p_Sock;
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");
            m_out = new PrintWriter(m_Sock.getOutputStream(), true);     
            InputStreamReader isr;
            m_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_Sock.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));          
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                char buf[];
                while (true) {
                    String inputLine = "";
                    while (m_in.ready()) {
                        int i = m_in.read();
                        m_out.write(i);
                        inputLine += (char)i;
                    }
                    if (inputLine.length()>0) {
                        System.out.println(inputLine);
                        m_out.flush();
                        inputLine = "";
                    };
                }
                //System.out.println("Connection closed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Exception:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Echo Socket accepting connections on port 1423");
            ServerSocket sSock = new ServerSocket(1423);
            while (true) {
                Connection c = new Connection(sSock.accept());
                c.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**EchoClientTest:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EchoClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[] keyB = {
                    (byte)0x2C, (byte)0xCF, (byte)0xBC, (byte)0x81, (byte)0x99, (byte)0xB7, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x84, 
                    (byte)0xD1, (byte)0x09, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x4F, (byte)0xB6, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x1F, 
                    (byte)0x17, (byte)0x61, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0xD7, (byte)0x43, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x6C                      
            };
            byte[] ivB = {
                    (byte)0x7B, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0x36, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0x26, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0x5E                      
            };


            {
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1423);
                System.out.println("Connected");

                System.out.println("Setting up - Unencrypted version");
                OutputStream oS = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream doS = new DataOutputStream(oS);
                InputStream iS = echoSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(iS,"UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);


                System.out.println("Writing Unencrypted output");
                doS.write("Test Message\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                doS.flush();

                System.out.println("Waiting 1 second");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println("Reading data from socket");

                String inputLine = "";
                while (bR.ready()) {
                    int i = bR.read();
                    inputLine += (char)i;
                }
                if (inputLine.length()==0) {
                    System.out.println("Error nothing read from socket");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Recieved:" + inputLine);
                    inputLine = "";
                };

                System.out.println("Closing Socket");
                echoSocket.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Repeating but encrypting the data SENT on the socket");
            {
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1423);
                System.out.println("Connected");

                System.out.println("Setting up Ciphers");
                String Algo = "DESede"; //DES or DESede

                final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyB, Algo);
                final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivB);
                final Cipher cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CFB8/NoPadding");
                cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);      

                System.out.println("Setting up - Encrypted version");
                OutputStream oS = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
                CipherOutputStream cipherOutputS = new CipherOutputStream(oS,cipherEncrypt);
                DataOutputStream doS = new DataOutputStream(cipherOutputS);
                InputStream iS = echoSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(iS,"UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);


                System.out.println("Writing Encrypted output");
                doS.write("Test Message\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                doS.flush();

                System.out.println("Waiting 1 second");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println("Reading data from socket");

                String inputLine = "";
                while (bR.ready()) {
                    int i = bR.read();
                    inputLine += (char)i;
                }
                if (inputLine.length()==0) {
                    System.out.println("Error nothing read from socket");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Recieved:" + inputLine);
                    inputLine = "";
                };

                System.out.println("Closing Socket");
                echoSocket.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Repeating but encrypting the data SENT and decrypting RECIEVED on the socket");
            {
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1423);
                System.out.println("Connected");

                System.out.println("Setting up Ciphers");
                String Algo = "DESede"; //DES or DESede

                final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyB, "DESede");
                final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivB);
                final Cipher cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CFB8/NoPadding");
                final Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CFB8/NoPadding");
                cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);      
                cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);      

                System.out.println("Setting up - Encrypted version");
                OutputStream oS = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
                CipherOutputStream cipherOutputS = new CipherOutputStream(oS,cipherEncrypt);
                DataOutputStream doS = new DataOutputStream(cipherOutputS);
                InputStream iS = echoSocket.getInputStream();
                CipherInputStream cipherInputS =  new CipherInputStream(iS,cipherDecrypt);
                InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(cipherInputS,"UTF-8");
                BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);


                System.out.println("Writing Encrypted output");
                doS.write("Test Message\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                doS.flush();

                System.out.println("Waiting 1 second");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println("Reading data from socket (and Decrtpying)");

                String inputLine = "";
                while (bR.ready()) {
                    int i = bR.read();
                    inputLine += (char)i;
                }
                if (inputLine.length()==0) {
                    System.out.println("Error nothing read from socket");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Recieved:" + inputLine);
                    inputLine = "";
                };

                System.out.println("Closing Socket");
                echoSocket.close();
            }           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Example Client Output:**

```
Connected
Setting up - Unencrypted version
Writing Unencrypted output
Waiting 1 second
Reading data from socket
Recieved:Test Message

Closing Socket
Repeating but encrypting the data SENT on the socket
Connected
Setting up Ciphers
Setting up - Encrypted version
Writing Encrypted output
Waiting 1 second
Reading data from socket
Recieved:?Ip?????9?m?
Closing Socket
Repeating but encrypting the data SENT and decrypting RECIEVED on the socket
Connected
Setting up Ciphers
Setting up - Encrypted version
Writing Encrypted output
Waiting 1 second
Reading data from socket (and Decrtpying)
Error nothing read from socket
Closing Socket
```

Note: I have a situation where TLS and certificates are not applicable. If it were possible I would of course use https rather than this method.

Comment: Get rid of the `ready()` test.

Comment: How should I be querying the stream to determine if bytes are ready to be read?

Comment: All `ready()` does is tell if you can read without blocking. So when it's false that just means the read will (actually, may) block. You are interpreting this as an error. You should just read until EOF.

Comment: You should create a message protocol on top of the streams instead. You can always concatenate the packets back together again. Note that you can easily make this much more secure by using `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"`. If you have time left, add DH & authentication + a MAC over the messages.

Comment: I have a protocol in my main app (This is just a test) I am trying to upgrade the protocol to use encryption. I was trying to use triple DES rather than AES because I understand AES has been broken. (I will also use RSA Public keys with a random triple DES key being sent via RSA and nodes will have their public keys pre-shared via an alternative secure method)

Comment: GregS: In my app each connection has it's own thread. The thread is responsible for reading incoming messages and sending outgoing ones. I need a non-blocking method to read incoming messages otherwise outgoing messages will never get sent. I also can't read until EOF on the socket as the socket will never end.

Comment: AES is not broken. There is a bit of a problem when using AES-256 with related keys. That's mainly an issue if you want to build a hash function with AES as underlying cipher. 3DES is problematic because of the block size, the maximum key strength and the existence of weak keys (which may be more of a worry than the weak AES key schedule). Oh, and AES-128 is faster than 3DES most of the time.